# How to use an existing Drupal 7 User Database With PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to get a php login working for a Drupal 7 database so that I can use an existing user database.

I am using the following html form:

```
    <form id='login' action='http://www.example.com/login.php' 
`method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8' class="login100-form validate-form 
flex-sb flex-w">
                <span class="">
                        <tr>
    <td align="center">
    <img border="0" src="../logoac.jpg" width="70%"></td>
</tr>
                </span>


                <div class="" data- 
validate = "Username is required">
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="username" 
placeholder="Username">
                    <span class="focus-input"></span>
                </div>


                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-16" data- 
 validate = "Password is required">
                    <input class="input100" type="password" name="password" 
 placeholder="Password">
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="container-login100-form-btn m-t-17">
                    <button class="login100-form-btn">
                        Login
                    </button>
            </form>
```

And login.php that the form triggers is:

```
    <?
//set the working directory to your Drupal root
define("DRUPAL_ROOT",     "/xxx/web/xxx");

//require the bootstrap include
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL); 
global $user;

/(loads everything, but doesn't render anything)

$username = trim($_POST['username']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);

$form_state = array();
$form_state['values']['name'] = $username;
$form_state['values']['pass'] = $password;
$form_state['values']['op'] = t('Log In'); 

drupal_form_submit('user_login', $form_state);
$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
$_SESSION["UserID"] = $data["name"];

if($user->uid >0)
{
header('Location: http://www.example.com/otherpage.php');
}
else
{
header('Location: http://www.example.com/noaccount.php');
}
?>
```

This sort of works in that the user is logged in and redirected as above, but next time they visit how do I get them to automatically go to otherpage.php without having to login with the html form?

If they re-use the html form, they get caught up in some sort of Drupal automatic redirect to their Drupal user page for some reason rather than the redirects above working.  I think this is because they are already logged in and there is an open session but I cant get this to work.

So:
1. How can I get the form above to over ride the existing session?
2. Or better still, how do I get otherpage.php to check if an existing session is open and let them in to the restricted area or redirect them back to the login form if they are not logged in?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the function "drupal_form_submit" or re-write it to create your prescribed session . Drupal is very secure and create session / cookies which will re-direct a logged in user as you have mentioned . If you want a trick , then play here .

Comment: Thanks, can you point me in the right direction of how I might do this please?  I am trying to learn but have reached the limit of my available talent :)  What do you mean by play here?

Comment: You can play a trick here

$_SESSION["UserID"] = $form_state['values']['name'];

And in the top of the page write 

session_start();
if ($_SESSION["UserID"] != ''){//Re-Direct to otherpage}

Comment: Did you give it a try ?